# Calc2LaTeX crashing on Ubuntu 20.04/Libreoffice 6.4.7.2

Tags: tables, libre-office

I'm using LibreOffice 6.4.7.2 on Ubuntu 20.04, and trying to convert a Calc table to LaTeX code. When I run the Main macro, Calc2Latex crashes with the message BASIC Runtime Error: An exception occurred. Type com.sun.star.container.noSuchElementException.

The crash appears to be happening in the DialogLibraries.LoadLibrary( "Calc2LaTeX" ) function.
[image: Screenshot]
Any help will be appreciated. A screenshot is attached.

Thanks in advance

s1b

Comment: I'm sorry that you are having troubles but this does not seem to be related to LaTeX at all. You should probably ask on some support site for libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

Libre Office imports the extension .xlb file as library, but takes the name of the .zip file as library name, but calc2latex is expecting the library to be called "Calc2LaTeX". 
To fix this:

1. Go to **Tools**->**Macros**->**Organize Dialogs...**
2. Than open the tab **libraries**
3. Make sure calc2Latex is in there
4. Rename the library to "**Calc2LaTeX**" with the same upper-case and lower-case letters.